# Ionic-Angular get data from API --undefined and console.log order

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

everybody, I have a problem I haven't solved in about a week. I am developing an Ionic-Angular project and **I want to get data from my API**. I execute http function in constructor but the output comes after everything works. **When i use the variable of result the http in any function, it gives undefined.** Somehow I don't understand I can display in a page.html with {{result}}. I tried the async - await - promise, but I didn't succeed. I guess I didn't get the concept.

```
export class Tab1Page {

  apiRoot:string = "http://dengepvc.com/api.php";
  results;


  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    console.log("constructor");
    this.http.get(this.apiRoot).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data["lat"];
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterContentInit");
    // if i put here: console.log(this.results); it gives undefined.
  }
}
```

**And here is my console output order;**

```
constructor
ngOnInit
ngAfterContentInit
41.097792
```

What should I do - write code etc. Can you help me? I've been trying for a week.

Comment: What did you put in your `page.html`? It's `undefined` because it's asynchronous.

Comment: In page.html: <ion-label>{{results}}</ion-label> --it prints 41.097792.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem is you are doing an AJAX request (and it take some time) .. it responde to you with data in a time your Ionic app has already hooked in the AfterContentInitEvent .. even if you're doing it in the constructor .. So what you can do is:

1 - Subscribe for the response where you need it:

```
export class Tab1Page {

  apiRoot:string = "http://dengepvc.com/api.php";
  results;
  ajaxCall;

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    console.log("constructor");
    this.ajaxCall = this.http.get(this.apiRoot);
    this.ajaxCall.subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data["lat"];
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterContentInit");
    // subscribe again here for response if you really can't put all your logic only  in one subscribe


    this.ajaxCall.subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data["lat"];
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. But I have one more question. Can I use this.results variable from this.ajaxCall.subscribe's outside? I think , I can't. Should I do all my operations in subscribe? Thank you